# How to increase SMD codes readability

Tags: surface-mount

is there any substance to increase the SMD codes readability when the component is very small or has a poor print on it?
Some years ago I saw a video where they suggest to use alchol, but I tried without success.

Comment: For IC's where the markings are engraved rather then printed you can try putting on the tiniest bit of silicon heatsink compound and then wiping it off. The compound gets stuck in the engraving, making it readable.

Comment: Use a polarizing camera filter. Rotate the filter slowly as you look through it. Also rotate the SMD device to alter the incident angles of the light source.

Comment: How about a microscope?

Comment: Oblique reflected light will improve contrast ratio into lens